# Unset session issue when logout

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, session-variables

I have created a website which has a front end and back end panel. On both panel I have created login area, front for user's login and back end for admin's login which can manage all the activity of front end users. I also have two different table for login, user's login detail and admin's login detail. 
It is working properly when I login on both panel at the same time in two different tabs. In this case two different session are created $_SESSION['adminName'] and $_SESSION['userName'] and both are accessing their allocated data. 
But the problem is created when I logout from anyone of the panel. When I logout from the front end, the back end admin is automatically logout by destroying all session of website. however I have two different logout function just like two login function for login.

the logout function for user contain following code.

```
   session_start();
   unset($_SESSION);
   session_destroy();
    echo '<script>
         window.location.href = "'.$site_path.'";
        </script>';
```

and what I want that both the logout function work only for their panel. they does not destroy the other panel's session.

Anyone have any idea how to solve this issue and what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: try `foreach ($_SESSION as $value) {
   unset($value);
}`

Comment: You should be able to do 
unset($_SESSION['adminName']; to unset this session alone

Comment: @user2092317 You put `&` instead of `$` ;)

Comment: thanks for unset(Session['adminName']) its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the `session_destroy()` and make the unset more specific, say `unset($_SESSION['userName'])` to logout from the main site and `unset($_SESSION['adminName'])` when you want to log them out of the admin panel. Using `unset($_SESSION)` is definately not recommended.

As long as both panels require each session variable individually you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to unset session variables this way.
 Use session_unset(), see http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php
Over that, you don't want that the session still exists on the users computer, for this use session_destroy().
session_unset() just clears out the session for usage.